# Timezone incorrect between startOf and endOf MomentJS methods

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Very odd issue using `momentjs`:

`moment().startOf('month').toDate()` produces:
`Sun Nov 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`

`moment().endOf('month').toDate()` produces:
`Mon Nov 30 2020 23:59:59 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)`

Why is there a change of timezone? Why does start choose `EDT` and the endOf chose `EST`?

Comment: Because on November 1st, 2020, [daylight savings time ended in the USA](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enKR923KR925&sxsrf=ALeKk02xFTBRS_oLuNDTnNSu1TIHhmkHNw:1606330757679&q=2020+daylight+savings+time+usa&spell=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjv1c-xsJ7tAhWUfd4KHQH7A3sQBSgAegQIDxAw&biw=1920&bih=890).

Comment: I don't believe that's the case as `moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month').toDate()` still produces `EDT`

Comment: That's because before November 1st, daylight savings time was still effective.

Comment: Oh my. Its `EDT` for half the year and `EST` for the other? What in the world.

Comment: I mean are you not from the USA? :)

Comment: I am.. I just thought they would adjust EST not change timezone names lol You can put that in the answer if you would like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startOf('month')` and `endOf('month')` returns the first and last date of the month in the browser's timezone.

On November 1st, 2020, [daylight savings time ended in the USA](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C5CHFA_enKR923KR925&sxsrf=ALeKk02xFTBRS_oLuNDTnNSu1TIHhmkHNw:1606330757679&q=2020+daylight+savings+time+usa&spell=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjv1c-xsJ7tAhWUfd4KHQH7A3sQBSgAegQIDxAw&biw=1920&bih=890), so up to November 1st, your browser's timezone will be EDT (if you're in the Eastern Timezone area), and after November 1st, it will be EST.

If you want to get a specific timezone-based time, you can use [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/).